# Shell always evaluates both factors of &&?

Tags: shell

When `$thing` is null this quits...

```
thing=`command_that_could_return_null`
echo "thing is" $thing
if [ -z $thing ]; then exit; fi
```

...but this...

```
if [ -n $thing ] && [ $thing = "special_value" ]; then
  do_the_special_thing
fi
```

comes out with

> `[: =: unexpected operator`

I don't understad.
When `$thing` is null the first factor of the `&&` evaluates to false and therefore the second should not be evaluated, but it appears that it *is* being evaluated?

I guess it's just a feature of `sh` that I have to write this as two `if`s?

Comment: Quotes are not optional. `[ -n "$thing" ]`

Comment: Otherwise it becomes just `[ -n ]`, which is true, when thing is empty.

Comment: You appear to be correct. Is there some documentation for this somewhere?

Comment: It follows from the documented behavior of parameter expansions, though the documentation isn't always explicit about the *consequences* of the defined behavior.

Comment: Furthermore, it appears to work _without_ quotes on a `sh` console, so why not when in a script file?

Comment: Whether it works without quotes depends on the value of `thing`.

Comment: @chepner do you have a reference for _the documentation_?

Comment: It works in a `sh` console when `$thing` is an unassigned variable -- as it is to start with in a new session.

Comment: What documentation do you want, the behavior of an unquoted parameter expansion, or the behavior of `[` with a single argument?

Comment: The thing to note is that this behaviour is NOT syntax specific to `if` or the square brackets - rather it is the end result of bash’s normal quote handling.   For references, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html especially 3.1.2 Quoting, and 3.5 Shell Expansions

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but `echo "thing is" $thing` indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of quotes.  It would be more correct to write `echo thing is "$thing"`, but best practice (arguably) would be `echo "thing is $thing"`.  There's no need to double quote a literal string. There is a need to double quote variables.

Comment: I'm more used to looking at something like `PRINT 'thing is ' + @thing` -- this is making no sense!

Comment: It makes sense if you read the documentation for the language you're writing code in, instead of assuming it'll behave like other languages you're used to. You might start with [BashParser](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) for a high-level overview of how command lines are processed, or the [Commands and Arguments section of the BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments) for something with more hand-holding.

Comment: The POSIX sh standard, which bash and all other POSIX shells comply with, is formally documented at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html -- the behaviors we're discussing here fall out directly from the contents of that specification.

Comment: BTW, re: *It works in a sh console when $thing is an unassigned variable -- as it is to start with in a new session* -- could you provide your exact test methodology for determining that? (Or is your "console" not really sh, but instead zsh? zsh is not a POSIX-compliant shell; one of the places where it breaks the standard is unquoted parameter expansion behavior).

Answer (score 0):

If you fix your quote problem (which @CharlesDuffy mentioned) - your bottom 3 lines work just fine:

```
if [ -n "$thing" ] && [ "$thing" = "special_value" ]; then
  do_the_special_thing
fi
```

Also, you referred to variables being "null", but the relevant term is a variable that is "unset". In Bourne shell terminology, "null" refers to the empty string.

Comment: @chepner: Right you are. fixed.